# Rewriting an infinite series as a rational function

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

Could someone please let me know if my steps are correct? I am trying to rewrite the first line as a rational function, $p(x)\over q(x)$

\begin{align}
& 3x^1+3x^2+9x^3+9x^4+27x^5+27x^6+\cdots \\[8pt]
= {} & 3x(1+x)+9x^3(1+x)+27x^5(1+x)+\cdots \\[8pt]
= {} & 3x(1+x)(1+3x^2+9x^4+\cdots) \\[8pt]
= {} & (3x+3x^2) {1\over 1-3x^2} \\[8pt]
= {} & 3x+3x^2\over 1-3x^2
\end{align}

Comment: Looks just fine.... for $\;|3x^2|<1\iff |x|<\cfrac1{\sqrt3}\;$ , of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your work seems correct to me.